# How can I edit TinyMCE.init() in Voyager?

Tags: laravel-5, tinymce, voyager

I've just started using Voyager, and I'd like to know if there's a way to override the basic settings contained in the tinymce.init() method included in Voyager's app.js file without having to go through the hassle of uglifying and editing that file (which seems to me like a terrible idea overall). Can tinymce.init() be overridden somehow?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can overwrite your tinymce.init()

do as follow

```
  if(user_id == 4){
       $("#txt_subject :input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
       tinyMCE.get('richtextdescription').setMode('readonly');
        /*Disable our description tinymce for developer user.*/
    }
```

you have to override the voyager template in your resource folder as follow

```
 resources/views/vendor/voyager/requirements/edit-add.blade.php
```

in ths file you can override default behaviour of the tinymce.init()

above code is for my project requirement. you can also do may customisation as per your need.

May i hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no way to do this in Voyager, you could write a simple abstraction for removing an editor and replacing it with one you define. I'm no Voyager expert, so it might be worth contacting the author of the TinyMCE module and asking for some kind of accessible configuration.

Answer (score 0):

*/vendor/tcg/voyager/publishable/assets/js/app.js
add
fontsizeselect to toolbar
and
after toolbar
fontsize_formats:'8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt',